# Add content-type for specific file types in Amazon CloudFront?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I have an S3-bucket, that I'm serving using CloudFront. And I want to serve some JSON-files from it.

Out of the box, the CF response doesn't contain any `Content-Type` headers at all for this file type. The file is just downloaded by the browser as any regular file. However, I want it to have a proper mime type header: `Content-Type: application/json`.

I know, I can set custom header for any single file manually in S3, however, is it possible to specify some rule for specific filename extensions to add specific HTTP headers to the response in Amazon CloudFront?

Answer (score 16):

The accpeted answer is outdated. Amazon CloudFront supports adding custom headers to specific file types, without using Lambda functions, by creating a behavior with a custom "Response headers policy" and origin override checked in the policy.

1. In CloudFront navigate to the "Behaviors" tab and click "Create Behavior"

[Create CloudFront Behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HArWM.png)

2. Specify the file types you want to target in "Path pattern", f.e. `.js` files.

[Add `*.js` in "Path pattern"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IP2BX.png)

3. Scroll down to "Response header policy" and click "Create policy"

[Click "Create policy" in "Response header policy"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9OJwG.png)

4. A new tab opens, click "Add Header" in "Custom Headers", set key to "Content-Type" and value to "application/javascript", click the checkbox "Origin override", then click "Create"

[Create a custom header in the new tab with "Origin override" checked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HAKI4.png)

5. Navigate back to the tab in which the CloudFront Behavior is created and search for the newly created response header policy (you need to refresh the selection box first), then click "Create Behavior".

All requests through the CloudFront CDN to `.js` files should now have the "Content-Type: application/javascript" response header.

Comment: This is great! Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Update: CloudFront itself does not provide a built-in mechanism for manipulating headers, but [Lambda@Edge](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-edge.html), used in conjunction with CloudFront, provides a mechanism to create hooks that can examine and modify origin response headers.  It can't actually examine the response body, but can inject static or heuristically-derived headers.  This is potentially a viable workaround if the content is from a known/trusted source and the content-type is known, but should probably not be used for user-submitted content, since an incorrect content-type could cause a browser to misinterpret the payload, and might be a potential exploit vector.  Setting the content-type on the object, correctly, when it is uploaded is probably still the better solution.

The original answer here pre-dates Lambda@Edge and refers to native capabilities of CloudFront itself.

---

CloudFront uses the response headers provided by the origin server, whether it's S3 or a custom origin.  CloudFront does not provide a mechanism to rewrite them or to add them.

The solution is to set the `Content-Type` on the object when originally uploading it into S3.

If you upload the file to S3 with `Content-Type` set, the same value will be returned when the object is downloaded (whether directly from S3 or through CloudFront).  Otherwise, you have to modify objects after upload if you don't want the default `Content-Type: binary/octet-stream` header that S3 assigns when you don't specify one.

Answer (score 5):

If you have no control over how objects are being uploaded to your S3 bucket, you could use a [Lambda@Edge](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-edge.html) function to override the response headers as follows:

(The downside to this method is that it increases latency and incurs additional costs)

1. Create an IAM policy that will be attached to your lambda function's role in the next step:

   ```
   {
       "Version": "2012-10-17",
       "Statement": [
           {
               "Sid": "StatementForCloudWatchLogs",
               "Effect": "Allow",
               "Action": [
                   "logs:CreateLogGroup",
                   "logs:CreateLogStream",
                   "logs:PutLogEvents"
               ],
               "Resource": "*"
           },
           {
               "Sid": "StatementForLambdaFunction",
               "Effect": "Allow",
               "Action": [
                   "lambda:EnableReplication",
                   "lambda:GetFunction"
               ],
               "Resource": [
                   "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:{YOUR_ACCOUNT_ID}:function:{FUNCTION_NAME}:{FUNCTION_VERSION}"
               ]
           },
           {
               "Sid": "StatementForIAMServiceLinkedRoles",
               "Effect": "Allow",
               "Action": [
                   "iam:CreateServiceLinkedRole"
               ],
               "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::{YOUR_ACCOUNT_ID}:role/*"
           },
           {
               "Sid": "StatementForCloudFrontDistributions",
               "Effect": "Allow",
               "Action": [
                   "cloudfront:CreateDistribution",
                   "cloudfront:UpdateDistribution"
               ],
               "Resource": "*"
           }
       ]
   }
   ```
2. Create a new AWS service IAM role for lambda and attach the policy you created in step 1 to it. Under **Trust relationships**, make sure you have both; `lambda.amazonaws.com` and `edgelambda.amazonaws.com` as trusted entities.
3. Create your lambda function and then publish a new version (Under **Actions**). You must create functions with the nodejs6.10 runtime property:

   ```
   'use strict';

   exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
      const response = event.Records[0].cf.response;

      if (response.status === '200') {
          response.headers['content-type'] = [{
              'value': 'application/json', // <-- Your desired content type.
              'key': 'Content-Type'
          }];
      }

      callback(null, response);
   };
   ```
4. Create a new behavior for json files in your CloudFront distribution (for example, `path/to/your/json/*.json`) and make sure it is placed above the `Default (*)` behavior.
5. Under **Lambda Function Associations** for the newly-created behavior, select the **Origin Response** event type and enter the ARN for your lambda function that was created in step 3. For example: `arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:{YOUR_ACCOUNT_ID}:function:{FUNCTION_NAME}:{FUNCTION_VERSION}`. (**NOTE**: Your lambda function must be created in the US East (N. Virginia) region and the function ARN must have a numbered version and not `$LATEST` or an alias).
6. Create a CloudFront invalidation for your `path/to/your/json/*` files.

Make sure you read the [Requirements and Restrictions on Lambda Functions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/lambda-requirements-limits.html).

See also [Lambda Event Structure](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/lambda-event-structure.html) for additional info.

Answer (score 1):

It would be a good idea to upload them with the Content type

[image]

To retrieve CloudFront objects with a specific content type, you should upload the object with the desired content type using the **s3.put_object** method. In your example code, you're uploading a JSON file to an S3 bucket:

```py
    with open('resources/avatar.png', "rb") as image_file:
        s3.put_object(Body=image_file, Bucket=user_bucket, Key=avatar_path, ContentType='image/png')
```

Here, you're setting the content type to application/json, which will ensure that CloudFront returns the correct content type in the response.

I hope this helps!